# What does condition ? Window.event : e mean?

Tags: javascript

So, I saw this video https://youtu.be/YylKa3C_qQc and it mentioned:

```js
const hotkeys = (e) => { let windowEvent ? Window.event : e; }
```

As a new JavaScript programmer, I don't know how this is working. How does this work? `windowEvent ? Window.event : e;`. All I know is that this is a ternary operator.

Comment: A [ternary operator (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is an in-line `if-else` shorthand.

Comment: `window.event` is a [quite old and nowadays deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) way of accessing a DOM event. I think the code you provided is either trying to be backward-compatible or very defensive. I personally haven’t seen it for a while, usually working with event handler arguments (in your example, it’s `e`) is enough.

Comment: Thanks. This small knowledge is going to go a long way